# Microsoft Access, Combining names and adding values

Tags: ms-access

I'm working on a Microsoft Access problem and I cannot figure this out with either code or the easy hub. I need to combine the ID's for the same customer and add the total sum. So for example "ID: 5" should have a total of "$39.90". How would I do this?

[image: Here is my sheet]

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't post a reproducible sample do data (you showed an image) and I don't have time to red0 everything, I'll show you how to do a GroupBy and Sum in Northwind.

[image]

Here is the SQL:

```
SELECT [Order Details].OrderID, Sum([Order Details].UnitPrice) AS SumOfUnitPrice
FROM [Order Details]
GROUP BY [Order Details].OrderID;
```

Here is the final result:

[image]